# How to compile Qt5 hello world in win10 with cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "hello world";
    return a.exec();
}
```

*CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.15.14\\msvc2019_64")
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
```

output:

```
====================[ Build | main | Debug-Visual Studio ]======================
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\dev\q0\cmake-build-debug-visual-studio --target main -j 6
[1/1] Linking CXX executable C:\dev\q0\bin\main.exe
FAILED: C:/dev/q0/bin/main.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=q0\main\CMakeFiles\main.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo q0\main\CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:C:\dev\q0\bin\main.exe /implib:C:\dev\q0\lib\main.lib /pdb:C:\dev\q0\bin\main.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  C:\Qt\5.15.14\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo q0\main\CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj /out:C:\dev\q0\bin\main.exe /implib:C:\dev\q0\lib\main.lib /pdb:C:\dev\q0\bin\main.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\Qt\5.15.14\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:q0\main\CMakeFiles\main.dir/intermediate.manifest q0\main\CMakeFiles\main.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(int &,char * *,int)" (__imp_??0QCoreApplication@@QAE@AAHPAPADH@Z) referenced in function _main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QCoreApplication::~QCoreApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QCoreApplication@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl QCoreApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QCoreApplication@@SAHXZ) referenced in function _main
C:\Qt\5.15.14\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
C:\dev\q0\bin\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

building manually with installed cmake, output:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32532.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32532.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (6.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/q0/build
MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET Framework

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/q0/q0/main/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  main.vcxproj -> C:\dev\q0\bin\Debug\main.exe
```

manual, installed cmake compiled, but the `main.exe` did not output anything (such "hello world" message) so is clearly not working correctly. How to fix this?

Comment: In the first  output you are building a 32 bit executable and trying to link to 64 bit Qt libraries. Your problem is you set the wrong architecture when at the configure step in CMake.

Comment: ***manual, installed cmake compiled, but the main.exe did not output anything (such "hello world" message) so is clearly not working correctly. How to fix this?*** You need to have the Qt dlls in the same path as your executable and also the platform plugin folder when you move to add a GUI.

Comment: @drescherjm thats why I have cmake command *set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...)* for the path.

Comment: ***thats why I have cmake command set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...) for the path*** This may solve the find_package() not finding Qt but does not solve the dlls being in a place your OS does not know when running your program.  Here is the Microsoft documentation on how and where windows searches for required dlls (and how you can help it): [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)

Comment: Yeah well, I said "fuck windows", and switched to ubuntu. Problem solved.

Comment: If you use Microsoft's `vcpkg` to install your dependent libraries it will automatically copy the required dlls to the same folder as your executables solving the problem. I do this on one of my Qt applications at work but use scripting for the others. I have developed Qt applications since 2008 using CMake + Qt . Some using vtk, itk, gdcm dcmtk .. as I do medical imaging research.